# ModSecurity blocking Openmanager plugin on TinyMCE in a Codeigniter environment

Tags: php, codeigniter, tinymce, mod-security, tinymce-plugins

I have a website hosted on Hostgator Cloud (running Linux Cent OS if that matters) and its built using Codeigniter.
I'm using the TinyMCE text-editor with [Openmanager plugin](https://github.com/rmorse/Open-Manager) for uploading images.

My installation directory structure looks something like this -

```
.
├── application
|   ├── controllers
|   ├── models
|   └── views
|       └── desktop
|           └── add_question.php
├── editor
|   └── plugins
|       └── openmanager
|           ├── editor_plugin.js
|           ├── editor_plugin_src.js
|           ├── encodeexplorer.php
|           ├── index.php
|           ├── assets
|           ├── langs
|           └── php
└── upload
    ├── index.php
    ├── equations
    |   ├── imageCapture.php
    |   └── img
    └── images
        └── thumbs
```

In `application/views/desktop/add_question.php` I've initialized my tinyMCE instance with tinyMCE.init and configured openmanager like this -

```
open_manager_upload_path: '../../../upload/',
```

Now when I try to use the plugin, I am shown this screen -

[image]

Upon consulting Hostgator, they showed me this error log entry from their side -

```
[error] [client 64.233.173.158]
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 2).
Match of "rx (/products/index\\\\.php\\\\?gallery=|connector=\\\\.\\\\./\\\\.\\\\./connectors|/admin/(?:structure/views/|[a-z]+/(?:edit|add))|/phpthumb\\\\.php\\\\?((?:w|h)=[0-9]+&)?((?:w|h)=[0-9]+&)?src=\\\\.\\\\./.*(?:pics|uploads|images)|/site-(?:builder|content)/|/node/(?:[0-9]+/( ..."
against "REQUEST_URI" required.
[file "/opt/mod_security/10_asl_rules.conf"] [line "199"] [id "340007"] [rev "42"] [msg "Generic Path Recursion denied"] [data "/../"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [hostname "example.com"] [uri "/editor/plugins/openmanager/index.php"] [unique_id "WCSMh2yz9j4AAakC028AAAPw"]
```

I'm not able to correctly decipher this error. What exactly is causing this error? The plugin and the whole application work properly on my localhost and another shared hosting account I have but it just fails on this Hostgator!

Answer (score 0):

Make a ‘.htaccess’ file with the following content and upload it.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

OR

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Adjust rewrite rule as per your requirement.

May be this will help.